# Swift 2 - remove NSDate values in array if value is before current date

Tags: ios, arrays, swift2, uilocalnotification

In my Application I create an array of "NSDate" in order to send local notifications. 
The values saved are "UUID" and "deadline" and they are saved using `let gameDictionary = NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults().dictionaryForKey(GAME_INFO) ?? [:]`

The result is somenting similar to this:

```
[{
    UUID = "546C5E4D-CFEE-42F3-9010-9936753D17D85";
    deadline = "2015-12-25 15:44:26 +0000";
}, {
    UUID = "7C030614-C93C-4EB9-AD0A-93096848FDC7A";
    deadline = "2015-12-25 15:43:15 +0000";
}]
```

What I am trying to achieve is to compare the "deadline" values with the current date and if the deadline is before than current date the values need to be removed from the array.

```
func compareDeadline()  {

        let gameDictionary = NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults().dictionaryForKey(GAME_INFO) ?? [:]
        var items = Array(gameDictionary.values)

        for i in 0..<items.count {

            let dateNotification = items[i]["deadline"]!! as! NSDate

            print(dateNotification)

            var isOverdue: Bool {
                return (NSDate().compare(dateNotification) == NSComparisonResult.OrderedDescending) // deadline is earlier than current date
            }

            print(isOverdue)

            if (isOverdue == true){
                items.removeAtIndex(i)
            }

        }
    }
```

When I try to remove the values from the array I get `Fatal Error: Array index out of range`

Any Idea How can I solve this?

Comment: as beyowulf sad. but there are more trouble with you code. you create an array based on some values, than you try to remove some of them and than ... than you simply never use the result. so, it is hard to say, what do you try to do, but you need to redesign the base idea first. do you want to update gameDictionary.values?

Comment: Yes this is whate I am trying to do

Comment: tried using `items = items.filter() { $0 as! NSDate != dateNotification}` but it still failing

Comment: To filter the values is easy. At first you need to create NSDate from your strings, you are not able simply cast the string to NSDate.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are a few problems. The reason you are getting an error is because you **cannot** remove elements while iterating inside **for-in** block. You can filter the items with the following code:

```
func compareDeadline()  {
  let gameDictionary = NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults().dictionaryForKey(GAME_INFO) ?? [:]
  let items = Array(gameDictionary.values)
  let currentDate = NSDate()
  let dateFormatter = NSDateFormatter()
  dateFormatter.dateFormat = "yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ssZ"

  let filteredItems = items.flatMap({
      guard let stringDeadline = $0["deadline"] as? String, let deadline = dateFormatter.dateFromString(stringDeadline) else {
        return nil
      }

      return deadline
  }).filter({
      currentDate.compare($0) == .OrderedDescending
  })
}
```

Comment: do you think that $0["deadline'] can be cast to NSDate?

Comment: I followed your lead because you didn't post where the array gets saved. If the date is really a string then you need to parse it with NSDateFormatter

Comment: it is no my question, just the notes for you. if you check my notes below the question, you can see there is a lot of other issues there

Comment: I added the appropriate date formatter in my answer.

Answer (score 2):

You should use the .filter method on the array to remove anything that you don't want in that array.  The result is a new array with just the filtered results.

.filter requires you to set the filter criteria in a closure that you send into it

[Here is a good article on how to use it](https://www.weheartswift.com/higher-order-functions-map-filter-reduce-and-more/)

Comment: func filter doesn't modify the array on witch you call it. Result returning from this function can be assigned to var to be mutable or to let to be immutable, as you decide.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `filter` method of swift array

For example to filter even numbers in array:

```
func isEven(number: Int) -> Bool {
  return number % 2 == 0
}

evens = Array(1...10).filter(isEven)
println(evens)
```